# how to store json response into model ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm not sure how to store json data into a model in the controller.  Here is my code.

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({


    actions: {
        login: function() {
            var data = this.getProperties("email", "password");
            console.log(data);
            return $.post('/', {
                email: data.email,
                password: data.password
            }).then(function(data) {
                if(data.isFail) {
                    return data;
                } else {

                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

after the line if(data.isFail) {....  I want to store the json data into a model.  How do I do this?

**UPDATE**
I went with Josh's suggestion of putting the action into the Route

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions : {
        login: function() {
            var data = this.getProperties("email", "password");
            console.log(data);
            return $.post('/', {
                email: data.email,
                password: data.password
            }).then(function(data) {
                if(data.isFail) {
                    store.createRecord('login', data);
                } else {

                }
                return data;
            });

        }

    }
});
```

No I'm getting an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined a `DS.Model` and if the contents of your JSON are a subset of the properties defined in your `DS.Model` then you can just do this:

```
store.createRecord('my-model-name', data);
```

This assumes that you have a `DS.Model` defined called `my-model-name.js` and that your JSON is in the `data` var.  If you have some properties in your JSON that are *not* defined in your `DS.Model`, I'm not sure how Ember Data reacts.

**UPDATE:** You asked about how to connect the route and the controller.  You can use this idiom:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        controller.set('myProperty', 'hello');
        controller.set('meta', this.store.metadataFor('org-user'));
    }
})
```

Note that this doesn't really relate much to your original question.

**UPDATE #2:**

Ok, it looks like you want to attempt a login, and then if the POST request succeeds, but the login itself fails (as indicated by the presence of an `isFail` property in the json response), then you want to create a new record in your local store?  Did I describe your intentions right?

My first question is, are you sure you want to create an Ember record here?  An Ember record is basically a "facsimile" of a "real" object that comes from your backend / database.  It makes sense to create a new local record if you want to eventually persist that somewhere (e.g. by calling `myRecord.save`).  Maybe you would create a local record for cacheing purposes only, but I personally have not seen that in the wild yet (but don't let me disqualify your usage if you've thought it through).

With that out of the way, let's assume you DO want to create a local record.  Then first we actually need a DS.Model that represents the record this will be.  I'll define mine like this:

**models/login.js**

```
DS.Model.extend({
   username: DS.attr('string'),
   password: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Note that I made sure to copy your properties from `this.getProperties()` because the way you're initializing your model with `createRecord('login', data)` means that what's in `data` needs to be a subset of what I just defined above.

Now that I have a model definition, I an get instances of this model from a backend via JSON (or any other format as long as I have the right serializer; Ember by default uses `RESTSerializer, which expects JSON).  I can also locally instantiate a new model, or in Ember speak, create a record.  Again, my goal in creating a new record is probably that I eventually want to persist it to my backend.  But since you're doing your own AJAX calls, I'll leave that part out.

Now onto your code, with slight revisions:

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions : {
        login: function() {
            var _this = this;
            var data = this.getProperties("email", "password");
            $.post('/', {
                email: data.email,
                password: data.password
            }).then(function(data) {
                if(data.isFail) {
                    var loginModel = _this.store.createRecord('login', data);
                    loginModel.save(); // not sure if you want to do this?
                } else {

                }                
            });
```

I took out the `return` statements because I'm guessing you don't need them (I may be wrong).  I also decided I would do something with the model instance we just created, in this case `save()` it, which will trigger a POST request to your backend, as determined by your adapter (by default Ember uses `RESTAdapter` to determine this).

Note also that I needed access to the current route instance via `this` but `this` takes on different meanings as I descend down the code, so I define `var _this = this;` at the top so I can reference the "real" this when I need it.

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: It is stating store is not defined.  I have App.Store = DS.Store.extend(); in my app.js.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: You can just use `this.store`.  I looked in the API docs for `Ember.Controller` (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html) and surprisingly, `store` is not defined! But if you look at  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.6.1/packages_es6/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/controller.js#L50 you can see it's available.  By the way, as you get deeper into Ember you'll learn of the "Ember Way". In this case, you should consider putting that logic in your Route since this relates to data.  See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_store.

Comment: I was looking for a discussion on the controllers vs route thing but couldn't find it. Basically, it is generally recommended that controllers be limited to "decorating" your model while the route is used to actually download / upload / push / store data.  Regarding `this`, take note of which context you're in (in your case, a controller).  `this` refers to one of those.  Then go to the Ember APIs to see what you can do with `this.`

Comment: I'm not sure how to connect the controller to the route.  I can't seem to trigger the route on the action login.  I have this setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    } but it only executes when page loads.  Is there one for when an action is executed?

Comment: Perhaps http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling is what you're looking for?  Both controllers and routes can define actions, but you have to define them within an `actions` property.  The example they have at that link should apply equally to controllers and routes.  Actions occur in response to some event that takes place, and are usually triggered by use of the `{{action 'myActionName'}}` usage in a Handlebars template.

Comment: Regarding connection a controller to a route, you got the right idea.  I'll post some updated code in my answer.

Comment: I actually switched it to your suggestion.  I updated my post with the new error I'm getting.  Where and what do I define normalize to be?

Comment: This error is occurring because when you call `store.createRecord` (by the way should that be `_this.store`? (where you have a `var _this = this;` as the very first line in your `login` function).  It's happening because `createRecord` apparently calls `normalize`, which is a method on `JSONSerializer` or `RESTSerializer` (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize), but instead of finding an instance of that object, somehow you're passing `undefined`. Hence, you can't call any function on a variable that's `undefined`. One moment for add'l suggestions.

Comment: That worked! The record is not being stored.  So the store function can only be accessed in the route or in the controller?